Saving Outlook mail into a network folder (not local drive) browsing for this folder
Is it possible to use the SHBrowseForFolder function to browse through network drives and folders?
Background: I want to save emails in the file system and need a convenient method to browse. An initial folder is provided (hard coded) to the routine.
Now I want to pass the initial folder to the function and ask the user if that is ok, otherwise browse for the folder to use.
I call the function from a sub. If I hit F1 in VBA Code Editor (Office 365), it sends me to a cryptic help page from Microsoft.
I found:
Private Function GetFileDir() As String
    
    Const PROCNAME As String = "GetFileDir"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim ret As String
    Dim lpIDList As Long
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim udtBI As BrowseInfo
    Dim RdStrings() As String
    Dim nNewFiles As Long

    'Show a browse-for-folder form:
    With udtBI
        .lpszTitle = lstrcat(EXM_016, "")
        'provide the initial folder
        .ulFlags = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS
    End With
    'standard Folder selection
    
    lpIDList = SHBrowseForFolder(udtBI)
    If lpIDList = 0 Then Exit Function
       
    'Get the selected folder.
    sPath = String$(MAX_PATH, 0)
    SHGetPathFromIDList lpIDList, sPath
    CoTaskMemFree lpIDList
    
    'Strip Nulls
    If (InStr(sPath, Chr$(0)) > 0) Then sPath = Left$(sPath, InStr(sPath, Chr(0)) - 1)

    'Return Dir
    GetFileDir = sPath

ExitScript:
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    GetFileDir = "ERROR_OCCURRED:" & "Error #" & Err & ": " & Error$ & " (Procedure: " & PROCNAME & ")"
    Resume ExitScript
End Function

Macro to save selected emails of Outlook in Windows folder doesn't answer my question.
The code saves the message in the local file system.
I have to save the mails on a network drive.

You cannot run a function. You call a function from a sub. Your initial F1 has to be in that sub.

Thanks niton, you're right, i call that function from a sub. F1 refers to inline help of VBA. Best regards, Chris

niton: it doesn't answer my question. The code shown is ok if i want t save the message in the local file system. I have to save the mails on a network drive. Meanwhile i found another code, wit the same issue. I'll keep searchng and trying! and post here if i find something satisfactory!

Intellisense does not suggest BrowseInfo for Dim udtBI As BrowseInfo. Likely other lines as well. Unless there is a way to convert the code you need something other than VBA.
